# W3C dom api in Java

Tags: java, xml

Take a look at the example code...

```
  NodeList folderNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("Folder");
  DocumentFragment node = (DocumentFragment) folderNodes.item(0);
```

It was very easy to do "getElementsByTagName" on the document but when I want to do this again on the DocumentFragment it seems I cannot.  How do I go about furthering this query?

Comment: Are you sure this is about Java and not JavaScript??

Comment: Yes, this is about the Java DOM api for parsting xml not the HTML dom api in a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Element` instead of `DocumentFragment`:

```
NodeList folderNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("Folder");
Element node = (Element)folderNodes.item(0);

NodeList subNodes = node.getElementsByTagName("OtherNodes"); // and so on...
```

The `Element` interface supports `getElementsByTagName`, whereas `DocumentFragment` is minimal and really doesn't do much.